# Create Web API using SQLite .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, sqlite, .net-4.5, plesk

I want to create a Web API in .NET Framework 4.5 (hosting enviroment that we are using requires only .NET 4 or 4.5 and not Core) using sqlite database. What is the right way to do implement a web api and connect it to the sqlite database in a way to deploy it directly through plesk? Please have in mind that we do not have a dedicated server and we are going to use Plesk to upload the published API.

Thanks in advance

I have already created the api, but I want some help with the creation of sqlite database and use of tables so to deploy it through Plesk.

Comment: I don't think this is the correct forum to ask an end-to-end howto. If you have a single issue that you need to address this is the place, but what you're asking is probably more complex than stack overflow is suited to.

Comment: Thanks but which forum is best for this kind of questions?

Comment: sqlite is self contained meaning that no extra work required to make it work. Just note that shared hosting usually only comes with 0.5GB of RAM. your API would probably consume 100-300mb so that only leaves around 200mb for your DB. And with a disk IO limit you won't get very far in terms of performance.

Comment: I understand your concern, I think I have 1G RAM and I/O 1000KB/sec. Unfortunately, I have to go with this. My question is how can I create an sqlite and use it at my get/post methods that I will create in web api in a way that I can deploy it directly to plesk?

Comment: you create it the same way as a desktop app. google it if you don't know how. then you deploy the db file to plesk as part of your deployment and you are done.

Comment: You mean to create a local db at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Use google and reseach. It's not a single issue.